# How can I display multiple line scenario text in extend reports?

Tags: cucumber, report, extent

In my feature file, using the same scenario I am checking more than one requirements. I have written the scenario like below:

```
Scenario: My first requirement ID
          My second requirement ID
          My third requirement ID
          Etc
```

After execution, the extend report shows only the result as

```
Scenario: My first requirement ID
```

How can I get all the three I D,s in extent report.

NOTE:Each of my scenario title is lengthy.

Comment: After " My first requirement ID" I press enter key and the next is given as a new line

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your scenario text a little bit more? According to [the documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/#write-a-scenario), the scenario should describe in human terms what we expect the software to do. It is quite unusual to include expected data in that scenario text. Are you using the ID from an enum? If that is the case, it would be better to spell out the enum in human readable terms. `Scenario: UserType is Administrator` for example. Another option would be to use a [Scenario Outline](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/), something like

```
Scenario Outline: My generic requirement statement
  Given Id <whateverId> is provided
  When I do <activity>
  Then I expect to see <result>

Examples:
  | whateverId | activity | result |
  | 12 | firstMethod | MyResult |
  | 20 | secondActivity | anotherResult |
  | 42 | thirdExample | thirdResult |
```

The variable names provided in the outline in angle brackets become the column headers in the examples grid. Just be sure to indent the grid below the `Examples:` line and also include the pipe `|` on both the left and right boundaries of the grid. Hopefully that helps.